# How can I use icons in navigation view's menu using icon font in android

Tags: android, font-awesome, navigationview, icon-fonts, android-navigationview

I am trying to migrate my android application which is using the png assets to icon fonts. I could successfully use it in navigation drawer using a list view. But I couldn't use it in navigation view by specifying it in the xml file of the menu.

**This is what I got when I tried with `Navigation Drawer`**

[image: When i tried with navigation drawer]

I don't know how will I use icon fonts in `navigation view` to get those marked icons.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_apple"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_apple"
        android:title="Apple" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chrome"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_chrome"
        android:title="Orange" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_left"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_left"
        android:title="Grapes" />
  </group>
```

How can I set those icons using icon font in this menu?

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167

Comment: @Rahul It says how to use font icons in android. The thing is that I need to use them in navigation view menu. The menu item needs a `textview` in order do so.

Comment: I will check and let u know

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `textView.setTypeface` where textView is item in your Navigation drawer. Also you need to have custom font with icons, put in to assets and then use it in code:

`Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), assetPath);
 textView.setTypeface(t);`

Comment: I'm trying to use my icon font in my navigation view's menu file, not in navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but You can use Textview instance of item and set typeface in java to it.

Comment: But the menu layout of navigation view doesn't have a text view. All it has got is the title and the icon (which i suppose is a imageview).

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/bg_all"

app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
app:theme="@style/list_item_appearance"
app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" >
```